# Target only Google Chrome on windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I need a jQuery function that replaces a css class, lets say .notchromewindows with .itischromewindows when the browser is chrome and running on windows.

It seems that the webkit on chrome windows is a bit different than on Mac.

I am a very basic Webdesigner. My javascript and jquery skills a very low. 
Would really appreciate if someone can walk me through this!

Comment: If you're a "basic" web designer, then I recommend finding styles that are common across major browsers.  These days they're generally compatible with only a few edge cases - you shouldn't need to be worrying about those edge cases at the "basic" level.  It may be that you need a "reset" css to start from a common blank slate.

Comment: Having said that, perhaps you could use https://stackoverflow.com/tags/modernizr/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the browser and OS platform using navigator api.

```
<!--HTML-->
<div class="notchromewindows">
....Some Content....
<div>
```

```
if((navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Windows') != -1) && (navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Chrome') != -1)) {
  $('.notchromewindows').addClass('itischromewindows').removeClass('notchromewindows');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried your solution but it doesn't take any effect. Do I need to put in front something? Like jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){ ?

Comment: Yes, you could put inside jQuery(document).ready function and also ensure that you running the script after the element rendered. It would be great if you add the script in the bottom of the page. Close the question if it works. :)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I pushed it in the footer. Unfortunately it doesn't have any effect. Here is again what I want to achieve: I do have a div tag connected with a CSS class called ".notchromewindows". This should be displayed on all devices and  browsers that is not google chrome on windows. If it is chrome running on windows the class ".notchromewindows" should be replaced with ".itischromewindows".

Comment: I made a edit in my answer. Please try that one and also in future please ask a question with the code if needed so it will help to understand better for everyone.
[Refer this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qk7pvujm/)

Comment: I tried but it gives me the following message:Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. So I am afraid I can upvote

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use Modernizr in this case
https://modernizr.com/docs/#using-modernizr-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code(both for Windows and MAC):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (/chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())
       ||/chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) 
        {$('body').`enter code here`addClass('chrome');} 
    else{  $('body').addClass('not-chrome');}
});
```